# Provide AWS KMS key when doing MultiPartUpload with S3 TransferManager

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

I am currently trying to use AWS S3 TransferManager to upload a file greater than 5GB to S3, since S3 requires multi part upload for files greater than 5GB.

I am using the following code to do this:

```
TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();
Upload up = tm.upload(bucketName, bucketKey, localfile);
up.waitForCompletion();
```

This achieves the behavior that I want, but I want to provide a KMS key to encrypt the file while uploading it to S3. Previously, I was using the PutObject API provided by S3 to do the uploads.

```
putObject(s3Client, bucketName, bucketKey, localFile, kmsKeyId)
```

How do I achieve the same behavior as putObject above with the transferManager upload?

Comment: SSE-KMS with the AWS-managed KMS key or your own KMS key? Or do you mean SSE-C with a CMK?